# Unable to specify .nsolid-proxyrc for Nsolid Proxy is causing issues

Tags: nsolid

We have a situation where we want to be able to start the Nsolid Proxy/Hub from an arbitrary folder. When we try to do this it fails due to not being able to find `.nsolid-proxyrc` in one of the parent folders.

We took a look at the source code for Nsolid Proxy and it looks like the library it is using, [rc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc), allows end-users to specify a file location, but Nsolid Proxy doesn't accept a CLI argument that allows us to specify it. It should be functionality that is easy to add, but it appears to be a closed source project.

**TL:DR;** We need to be able to specify the exact location of `.nsolid-proxyrc` when starting the hub. Is there a known work-around for this or is there a way we could request this feature gets added to the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the configuration file by using the `--config` flag (from `rc`) when starting N|Solid Proxy

```
$ nsolid proxy.js --config /path/to/config/file
```

By default it will look at the current working directory and then up the folder tree like node_modules then resort to the following locations:

- `$HOME/.nsolid-proxyrc`
- `$HOME/.nsolid-proxy/config`
- `$HOME/.config/.nsolid-proxy`
- `$HOME/.config/.nsolid-proxy/config`
- `/etc/nsolid-proxyrc`
- `/etc/nsolid-proxy/config`

Comment: This looks perfect @julianduque, I saw the CLI option mentioned in the `rc` documentation, but didn't know it was available to the proxy script. Now that you point it out, it makes sense that `rc` automatically picks up the CLI args for any script it is required into.

Thanks!